# Sequence proof (by induction, presumably) giving me trouble.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_1,...,a_n$ be a sequence of positive numbers.  Show that

$$(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)\left(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)\geq n^2$$

Hint:  Use the fact that for $x>0$ we have $x+(1/x)\geq 2$.

My idea is to use induction.  But I can't seem to make it work.  On the other hand, I don't see how the hint is going to take me where I need to go.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Arithmetic Mean Geometric Mean Inequality (AM/GM)?

Comment: If you mean the inequality $\sqrt{ab}\leq\frac{a+b}{2}$

Comment: I mean the generalization $\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{n}\ge (x_1x_2\cdots x_n)^{1/n}$.

Comment: I am NOT familiar with the general form.

Comment: No one has mentioned the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality so far. A proof using it is extremely direct, no thinking required at all.

Comment: See also: [Is it true that $\forall n \in \Bbb{N} : (\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} ) (\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_{i}} ) \ge n^2$ , if all $a_{i}$ are positive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3081320) and [How do I prove this using question using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2134362)

Answer (score 8):

Induction is not necessary. Note that:

\begin{align}
(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)&\left(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_n}\right) \\&= \left(\frac{a_1}{a_1} + \frac{a_1}{a_2} + \cdots + \frac{a_1}{a_n} \right)+\cdots + \left(\dfrac{a_n}{a_1}+\dfrac{a_n}{a_2}\cdots+\frac{a_n}{a_n}\right)\\&= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{a_i}{a_j} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\frac{a_i}{a_j} + \frac{a_j}{a_i}\right) \\
&\stackrel{*}{\geq} \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n 2 = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n 2n = \frac{1}{2}·2n^2 = n^2\end{align}

Where in $*$ we used the hint $x + \displaystyle\frac{1}{x} \geq 2$ taking $x = \displaystyle\frac{a_i}{a_j}$

Comment: change $\frac{a_i}{a_j} + \frac{a_j}{a_i}$ to $\left(\frac{a_i}{a_j} + \frac{a_j}{a_i}\right)$ will look better.

Answer (score 5):

This is equivalent to:

$$\frac{a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n}{n}\geq \frac{n}{\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{a_n}}$$

Where the LHS is the Arithmetic Mean and the RHS is the Harmonic Mean.

Those are power means defined as:

$$M_p = \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^na_k^p\right)^{1/p}$$

[It is known that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Proof_of_power_means_inequality) $M_p \geq M_q$ iff $p \geq q$.

Note that the Arithmetic Mean is $M_1$ and the Harmonic Mean is $M_{-1}$

Comment: You left to say "You were fast" and upvote :)

Comment: Do you know of a method that utilizes the given hint?

Comment: @user165130 check my other answer ;)

Comment: It looks good!  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Induction works just fine with the hint:

$$(a_1+\ldots+a_n)\left(\frac{1}{a_1}+\ldots+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)=(a_1+\ldots+a_{n-1})\left(\frac{1}{a_1}+\ldots+\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}\right)+\frac{a_1}{a_n}+\frac{a_n}{a_1}+\ldots+\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}+\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}+1$$

Comment: Ah, I think I see it now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly is valid for $n=1$. Assume that it holds for $n$ positive numbers.
$$\Big((a_1+\cdots+a_n)+a_{n+1}\Big)\Big((\frac{1}{a_1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_n})+\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}\Big)=(a_1+\cdots+a_n)(\frac{1}{a_1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_n})$$
$$+(\frac{a_1}{a_{n+1}}+\cdots\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}})+(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{1}}+\cdots\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}})+1$$
$$\geq n^2+\Big((\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{1}}+\frac{a_1}{a_{n+1}})+\cdots(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}+\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}})\Big)+1\geq n^2+2n+1=(n+1)^2.$$
Notice that $x+\frac{1}{x}\geq 2$ as long as $x>0.$